# 403 Forbidden Error when connecting React and Flask

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flask

Currently trying to connect some Flask code to my React website, but keep getting the 403 forbidden error.
Here's my python file, api.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, origins="*")

@app.route('/api', methods = ['GET'])
def index():
    return {
        'name':'Hello World',
        'author': 'me',
        'hello': 'world'
    }
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

While, here's my react file that I'm using to fetch this information, CardPage.js,

```
import React from "react";
import Card from '../components/Card';
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function CardPage() {

    const [card, setCard] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('/api').then(response => {
            if(response.ok) {
            return response.json()
        }
    }).then(data => console.log(data))}, [])

    return(
        <>
        <Card></Card>
        </>
    )
}

export default CardPage
```

However, whenever I check my console, I'm consistently met with this error:
CardPage.js:10
GET http://localhost:3000/api net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)

Here is my package.json, as well:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5000/",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm completely stumped, to say the least. Any tips?

I've tried adding and removing CORS, along with changing the port in my app.run, but to no avail.

Comment: The `fetch('/api')` is resolving with the 403 status returned from the backend. You'll need to investigate there (the backend) why a 403 is returned. Is there more to your backend code than you've shared here? Are there any server logs you can check? Is `http://localhost:3000/api` the correct URL for the request? What port is the backend running on?

Comment: got it to work! turns out i never did pip install flask_cors on my api.py file, so it wasn't recognizing it, so I'm assuming it was a CORS issue that was fixed with that import. I also didn't realize that I need to have my python file/flask running at the same time, since I'm pretty new to React and Flask. Thank you for the quick response!